# Facebook like button and twitter button needs to be on the same line

Tags: html

I'm trying to have my Facebook like button and twitter button line up on the same line. With the code below, my twitter button is not quite on the same line but not really on the second line either. Could someone please help me align these buttons on the same line. below is the code:

```
<p> 
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/gbhuffington" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" style=" width: 200px; clear: none; float: left; "></div>
</p>
<p style="width: 200px; float: left; clear: none;">
<a href="https://twitter.com/GBHuffington" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @GBHuffington</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
</p>
```

Comment: your problem seems to be related to CSS. Read about `position` and `float`. Also, consider using something like 960 or Blueprint for CSS

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't put them in seperate paragraphs.

[Here they are displaying inline for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/F6t2H/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the fb script in a `<div>` and twitter in a separate div.
2. Float the fb div right like this (`div style="float:right;"`)
3. Float the twitter div left (`div style="float:left;"`)
4. Your next content or line should start with `div style="vertical-align:bottom;"` to place the content at the bottom
   of the twitter div.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your floated `<p>` should be coded *before* the non-floating `<p>` (or put them in the same paragraph, like Samwise suggested).
2. Remove the `data-width` attribute from your `<div class="fb-like">` tag (in many cases, it makes it impossible to put anything on the same line).

As follows:

```
<p style="width: 200px; float: left; clear: none;">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/GBHuffington" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @GBHuffington</a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
</p>
<p> 
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/gbhuffington" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" style="clear: none; float: left;"></div>
</p>
```